# losing focus in Date Time Picker

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm trying to implement custom search between tow dates with other custom search fields, like text boxes and check boxes, but when I use date time picker in my search criteria I can get an accurate search, but in second time the date term will be used even I didn't use it this is because I am using > dtp_fromDate.Focused
Like this:

```
if (dtp_FromDate.Focused)
{
    tmpPersons = ctx.People.Where(c => c.InsertDate >= dtp_FromDate.Value).ToList();
}
if (dtp_ToDate.Focused)
{
    tmpPersons=ctx.People.Where(c => c.InsertDate >= dtp_ToDate.Value).ToList();               
}
```

**My Questions are:**

1# is there a way to losing focus after the search result bounded to a view? something like: `dtp_FromDate.Focused=false`

2# is there a better way to implement using DateTimePicker in search criteria better than what I'm using?

thanks.

**PS:** I searched a lot in web for this but no result could be satisfied!

Comment: Where do you place the code above? Anyway **it's very unreliable** to involve something relating to `focus` here.

Comment: I know that but how about the better way? there is a button to search and I don't want to add check boxes to validate if control will be in search cirteria

Comment: I still don't get what you want with your code, you have 2 `DateTimePickers`, 1 for `from date`, 1 for `to date` but the queries in 2 `if-statements` have the same logic? (both use the `>=` operator to filter the result)? I though it should be `>=` for `from date` and `<=` for `to date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of relying on focus, what about checking if the control has a value?

the way it is implemented in the code that you have posted it means that you can either set the from date or the to date, isnt it?

also in the to date query, it should be <=

this should solve your problem if I have understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I do see this:

```
if (dtp_ToDate.Focused)
{
    tmpPersons=ctx.People.Where(c => c.InsertDate >= dtp_FromDate.Value).ToList();               
}
```

This is querying from `dtp_FromDate` again - shouldn't you be pulling from `dtp_ToDate`, like so?

```
if (dtp_ToDate.Focused)
{
    tmpPersons=ctx.People.Where(c => c.InsertDate <= dtp_ToDate.Value).ToList();               
}
```

Comment: I've update my code, it's my bad when I copied the code to here.the problem not in the current code. the problem is how to lose focus or better approach to search

Answer (score 0):

for the focus: you can try setting focus to something else after the search
like: abc.Focus();